# Symmetry of non-surjectivity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\zeta:=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ be series, in which $x_k\in \left\{0,\frac{1}{2^k}\right\}$. Then $\zeta\in [0,1]$, since

$$\zeta\le \sum_k \frac{1}{2^k}=1, \zeta \ge \sum_k 0=0$$

It can be proved that there is a series $\zeta$ for every number in $[0,1]$. Suppose that there exists $y\in[0,1]$ such that there is no series representation of the form $\zeta$, i.e. such that $\zeta = y$. Then how does one prove that if this is the case then $1-y \not \in [0,1]$ either? Intuitively this seems to be the case, but I'm having difficulty proving this formally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the contrapositive:

$$(y\neq\zeta\Rightarrow1-y\neq\zeta)\Leftrightarrow(1-y=\zeta\Rightarrow y=\zeta),$$

where $\zeta$ means a representation of the from $\zeta.$

If $1-y=\sum_k x_k,$ then define $z_k=0$ if $x_k=1/2^k$ and $z_k=1/2^k$ if $x_k=0.$ Then,

$$\sum_kz_k=1-\sum_kx_k=1-(1-y)=y.$$